# One big StatefulWidget or multiple small StatefulWidgets

Tags: flutter, dart, statefulwidget

I have a UI that has 20+ small widgets that need to update simultaneously, while some widgets remain Stateless. I was wondering if it is more efficient to have the whole UI updated rather than having each one updated individually.

In a broader scope, should I **always** opt out to having multiple, small `StatefulWidgets` updated rather  than the whole UI, regardless of the number of widgets, considering that the widgets will be updated simultaneously? If not, is there any good measurement I can use to know how should I make that decision?

Comment: Hi! I guess multiple widgets is better than one big widget in terms of code style. As for efficiency and performance, you can measure it using performance view from devtools. But i guess there is no any significant difference. https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/devtools/performance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Late reply but it might help someone.

**TL;DR; Use multiple smaller widgets.**

I'm just working on a game where player has some time based reward boxes to open.

I had a dilemma if I should create:

- one Timer in the **"parent" stateful widget and pass down the time to stateless children.**

[image: Timer in parent]

- multiple timers in **smaller stateful children widgets**

[image: Timers in children]

You can see the performance results from dev tools (it was even better after I made some improvements).

*Of course please keep in mind that every case might be slightly different and results may vary :)*

Answer (score 1):

From the performance perspective, it is always wise to update each widget individually when needed.

Suppose, you have consolidated all widgets into one. Now if you need to update just one single text(and suppose that was a single widget previously), Flutter has to update the whole big widget for just one minimal change. Though Flutter won't complain about that because Flutter is pretty fast in rerendering but it will depend on the mechanism of the widget itself which might result in frame skipping/lag issue.

In another case, if all widgets are separated with their own functionality, Flutter just needs to destroy the individual widget that needs updating and rerender it. So it is a lot faster to render one widget than rendering 20+ widgets at once.

I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

**Depends on your needs**

Keep in mind that everything has a price, try to use `StatefulWidget` only for the dynamic widget. I often use a single StatefulWidget because only on StatefulWidget we can have nice compact state management while using the stateless widget for the children's which doesn't need state management (stateless).

It's worth checking the flutter.dev again to refresh our perspective about how StatefulWidget works https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/interactive. Because if you have a concern about performance you also need to avoid using setState() for the small updates while your page contains a lot of children because every setState() fired, your widget tree would be rebuild.

And also if you are building more complex apps, check this out https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple this is way more efficient and performance-friendly because with the provider we can concentrate on the dynamic widget only and leave everything static even everything was written above StatefullWidget.